# "Waiting for change log lock..." in liquibase while databasechangeloglock is empty

Tags: liquibase

I accidentally interrupted applying of `liquibase` script. Now I get message

> Waiting for change log lock...

Table `databasechangeloglock` is empty. Also I tried to add row 1   `false  (null)  (null)`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found problem. Lock was in databasechangloglock table in default postgresql database named "postgres".

Answer (score 7):

To list all the changeloglocks in postgres.

```
select * from databasechangeloglock;
```

To release a particuler lock.

```
update databasechangeloglock set locked ='f' where id=<id>;
```

Confirm with the `locked by` column before releasing.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend running the Liquibase commmand "releaseLocks" instead of directly updating the databasechangeloglock table.

The table's data-types and the update statement needed will changes depending on the DBMS platform you are using, but the "releaseLocks" command is universal.

Answer (score 0):

My case is different, after getting locked error,
I tried removing lock by setting locked = false
but it was not working turns out that I was not **committing** the update command.
-_-

Answer (score 0):

**for below query worked**

```
update databasechangeloglock set locked = 'False' where id = <id>;
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I had to update the below query with the schema

```
UPDATE {schema}.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED=false, LOCKGRANTED=null, LOCKEDBY=null where ID=1
```